# "No such file or directory" what's wrong in this Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I am playing with a Dockerfile and I have this:

```
ARG PUID=1000
ARG PGID=1000
RUN groupadd -g $PGID docker-user && \
    useradd -u $PUID -g docker-user -m docker-user && \
    mkdir /home/docker-user/.composer

COPY container-files/home/docker-user/.composer/composer.json /home/docker-user/.composer
RUN chown -R docker-user:docker-user /home/docker-user/.composer
USER docker-user
RUN composer global install
```

But when I try to build the image it ends with the following error:

```
Step 6 : COPY container-files/home/docker-user/.composer/composer.json /home/docker-user/.composer
lstat container-files/home/docker-user/.composer/composer.json: no such file or directory
```

The file does exist on the host as per this output:

```
$ ls -la workspace/container-files/home/docker-user/.composer/
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 rperez rperez 4096 Oct  5 11:34 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 rperez rperez 4096 Oct  5 11:14 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rperez rperez  208 Oct  5 11:20 composer.json
```

I have tried also this syntax:

```
COPY container-files /
```

But didn't work either. So I should ask: what's wrong? Why this keep failing once and once? What I am missing here?

Comment: where's located Dockerfile?

Comment: @Federkun this is the command I am running to build the image `docker build -t reypm/workspace -f ./workspace/Dockerfile .` in other words: I am in the root folder while the `Dockerfile` is at `workspace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) addresses this with:

> By default the docker build command will look for a `Dockerfile` at
>   the root of the build context. The `-f`, `--file`, option lets you
>   specify the path to an alternative file to use instead. This is useful
>   in cases where the same set of files are used for multiple builds. The
>   path must be to a file within the build context. *If a relative path is  specified then it is interpreted as relative to the root of the context.*

In this case I think is

```
COPY workspace/container-files/home/docker-user/.composer/composer.json /home/docker-user/.composer
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked, adding `workspace` at the beginning of the path do the job